# Flatten pandas object to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to flatten a list from a DataFrame. My existing DataFrame looks like this:

```
CreationDate
2013-12-22 15:25:02                    <ubuntu><mac-osx><syslinux>
2009-12-14 14:29:32    <ubuntu><mod-rewrite><laconica><apache-2.2>
2013-12-22 15:42:00                 <ubuntu><nat><squid><mikrotik>
Name: Tags, dtype: object
```

Then, I clean up the tag strings in the `Tags` column:

```
def tag_cleaner(s):
    s0 = "".join(s.split("<")).split(">")
    return [i for i in s0 if i != ""]

df["Tags"] = df["Tags"].apply(lambda t: tag_cleaner(t))
df["NumTags"] = df["Tags"].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

Which results in this:

```
CreationDate
2013-12-22 15:25:02                  [ubuntu, mac-osx, syslinux]        3
2009-12-14 14:29:32  [ubuntu, mod-rewrite, laconica, apache-2.2]        4
2013-12-22 15:42:00               [ubuntu, nat, squid, mikrotik]        4
```

Now, I create new columns for each tag:

```
tag_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, data=df["Tags"])
max_cols = tag_df["Tags"].map(len).max()
for col in range(max_cols):
    tag_df[col] = pd.Series(index=tag_df.index)
```

Which gives me this:

```
CreationDate
2013-12-22 15:25:02                  [ubuntu, mac-osx, syslinux] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2009-12-14 14:29:32  [ubuntu, mod-rewrite, laconica, apache-2.2] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2013-12-22 15:42:00               [ubuntu, nat, squid, mikrotik] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

For each tag in the `Tags` column, I would like to insert the tag at it's appropriate "index" column. So, the end result should look like this:

```
CreationDate
2013-12-22 15:25:02                  [ubuntu, mac-osx, syslinux] ubuntu     mac-osx syslinux        NaN NaN
2009-12-14 14:29:32  [ubuntu, mod-rewrite, laconica, apache-2.2] ubuntu mod-rewrite laconica apache-2.2 NaN
2013-12-22 15:42:00               [ubuntu, nat, squid, mikrotik] ubuntu         nat    squid   mikrotik NaN
```

I've tried `pd.DataFrame.insert()` and varying forms of creating new DataFrames and merging them together, I just can't seem to find the right combo. How do flatten each object in the `Tags` column to it's appropriate column on the same row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [.str.extractall()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) method in this case:

```
In [57]: df
Out[57]:
         CreationDate                                         Tags
0 2013-12-22 15:25:02                  <ubuntu><mac-osx><syslinux>
1 2009-12-14 14:29:32  <ubuntu><mod-rewrite><laconica><apache-2.2>
2 2013-12-22 15:42:00               <ubuntu><nat><squid><mikrotik>

In [58]: x = df.pop('Tags').str.extractall(r'\<(.*?)\>').unstack()

In [59]: x.columns = x.columns.droplevel(0)

In [60]: df.join(x)
Out[60]:
         CreationDate       0            1         2           3
0 2013-12-22 15:25:02  ubuntu      mac-osx  syslinux        None
1 2009-12-14 14:29:32  ubuntu  mod-rewrite  laconica  apache-2.2
2 2013-12-22 15:42:00  ubuntu          nat     squid    mikrotik
```

**UPDATE:** assuming that the data is a Series, not a DataFrame:

```
In [14]: s
Out[14]:
CreationDate
2013-12-22 15:25:02                    <ubuntu><mac-osx><syslinux>
2009-12-14 14:29:32    <ubuntu><mod-rewrite><laconica><apache-2.2>
2013-12-22 15:42:00                 <ubuntu><nat><squid><mikrotik>
Name: Tags, dtype: object

In [15]: type(s)
Out[15]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [16]: x = s.str.extractall(r'\<(.*?)\>').unstack().rename_axis(None)

In [17]: x.columns = x.columns.droplevel(0)

In [18]: x
Out[18]:
match                     0            1         2           3
2009-12-14 14:29:32  ubuntu  mod-rewrite  laconica  apache-2.2
2013-12-22 15:25:02  ubuntu      mac-osx  syslinux        None
2013-12-22 15:42:00  ubuntu          nat     squid    mikrotik
```

Comment: This ones more elegant!

Comment: That is definitely a lot closer than me! It doesn't work, though. `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'` I think it's because my DF is a series. Here is how you can get the real dataset and some of my code that will replicate the question for you. https://bitbucket.org/snippets/lloydm/jpnLM

Comment: Yeah, sorry, hit enter too soon! See above comment.

Comment: @mynameismevin, please check UPDATE. I was confused by this: `My existing DataFrame looks like this`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So, both worked, but apparently there were duplicate indices? I wasn't aware of that, however some index manipulations with `df = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='CreationDate', keep='last').set_index('CreationDate')` were helpful and put everything back into the proper place. Once I did that, `df["Tags"].str.extractall(r'\<(.*?)\>').unstack()` put things back into place for me. I got this error when trying to call `rename_index()`: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rename_index'`, so I just left it out. Seems to solve my problem, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think that was what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Partial solution for getting length and converting to list.

```
df.Tags = df.Tags.str.strip('<>')
df.Tags = df.Tags.str.split('><')
df['NumTags'] = df.Tags.apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

---

**Working solution**
Just comment out the comments and copy to clipboard and then comment them back again. Then run the code.

```
import pandas as pd

# CreationDate
# 2013-12-22 15:25:02                    <ubuntu><mac-osx><syslinux>
# 2009-12-14 14:29:32    <ubuntu><mod-rewrite><laconica><apache-2.2>
# 2013-12-22 15:42:00                 <ubuntu><nat><squid><mikrotik>
df= pd.read_clipboard()
df2= df.copy()
df2.CreationDate = df2.CreationDate.str.strip('<>')
df2.CreationDate = df2.CreationDate.str.split('><')
df2['Length'] = df2.CreationDate.apply(lambda x: len(x))

for a in range(df2.Length.max()):
    df2[a]=df2.CreationDate.apply(lambda x: x[a] if a<len(x) else 'NaN')
df2
```

Output:

[image]